# android ListView with image and text

Tags: android, list

I've searched alot about ListView and adapters, but can't really udnerstand how it works. Basically what I need is 10 rows with a image + text, so I can click on every row and do something. Could please someone provide the code for this? I really can't figure out how to create an adapter and then setting listener on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have you checked the following link?? if not then check it. Surely it
  will help you.

  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
     http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/
      http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/